# Using custom extension (/x) in resharper 9.0 command line inspection

Tags: resharper, command-line-tool, code-inspection, resharper-9.0

So I've got a custom nuget package I build which is installed in vs2013 through the ReSharper extension manager interface.  I remember back with resharper 8.2 I could specify a plugin parameter `/plugin=xxx.dll` to import a custom plugin but with the updated command line tools for resharper 9.0 it seems that the only way is to provide a package Id from the ReSharper Gallery.
Does this mean that my custom package with a unique id can't be imported unless I put it on the ReSharper Gallery?  Are the command line inspections now dependent on Visual Studio and ReSharper being installed?
quite confused, if anyone has any docs pertaining to this or info would be super helpful, [this](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/NETCOM/Introducing+InspectCode#IntroducingInspectCode-Settings) is all I could find.
Thanks for the help!

Edit: Plugin & Extensions mean the same thing in this context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid, this functionality was lost in 9.0 release (really both ways to use plugins in CLT are broken).

Comment: Ok, thanks for letting me know!  Would be really nice to get this functionality back again some day but for now I guess back to the 8.2 CLT